# i want to remove spaces from a string to check if its palendrome but it keeps adding letters in C

Tags: c, string

***the issue i have is that the code keeps adding letters after the 'for' code, if i write "ni pratar bra latin" it will become "nipratarbralatintin" with an exta "tin"***

```
    int ret1;
    int size = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char ch[100];


    printf("WELCOME USER\n");
    printf("ENTER A SENTENCE OR A WORD FOR THE PROGRAM TO START.\n");
    printf("THE PROGRAM WILL CHECK IF YOUR SENTENCE / WORD IS A PALENDROME");
    printf("\n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &ch);
```

---

**Removes spaces aka the part im having issues with**

```
    for (i = 0, size = 0; i < strlen(ch); i++) {
        ch[i - size] = ch[i];
        if (ch[i] == ' ')
            size++;
    }
    ch[i] = '\0';

    ret1 = isPalindrome(ch);
    int quit;

    if (ret1 == 1)
        // 1 means string is palendrome
        printf("\nYOUR SENTENCE/WORD: %s IS A PALENDROME", ch);
    else if (ret1 == 0)
        // 0 means string is not palendrome
        printf("\nYOUR SENTENCE/WORD: %s IS NOT A PALENDROME", ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
    ch[i] = '\0';
```

is wrong. The line is meaningless because `\0` will already be there on `ch[i]` because it is after exiting the loop with the condition `i < strlen(ch)`.

The line should be

```
   ch[i - size] = '\0';
```

to maintain consistency with the line inside the loop `ch[i - size] = ch[i];`.

Also the line

```
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &ch);
```

is wrong because `char(*)[100]` is passed where `char*` is expected and *undefined behavior* is invoked.

It should be

```
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", ch);
```

without the extra `&`.

This version with checking is better:

```
   if (scanf(" %[^\n]s", &ch) != 1) {
       fputs("read error\n", stderr);
       /* exit program (return from main(), using exit(), etc. */
   }
```

Comment: With a width limit, `scanf(" %[^\n]s"`  has same problems as [gets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).  There is no reason for the `"s"` in  `" %[^\n]s"`.  Consider `" %99[^\n]"`.